# Is this 8051 ASM function as unnecessarily convoluted as I think, or is there something I'm missing?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, microcontroller, 8051, bare-metal

I'm reverse engineering some firmware I dumped from an embedded device that uses an 8051 microcontroller. And I came across this function, which Ghidra disassembles as follows:

```
undefined FUN_CODE_1cff()
       undefined         R7:1           <RETURN>
            FUN_CODE_1cff
  1cff XCH  A,R5
  1d00 MOV  A,R7
  1d01 XCH  A,R5
  1d02 MOV  A,R5
  1d03 MOV  R2,A
  1d04 MOV  A,R6
  1d05 MOV  R7,A
  1d06 MOV  A,R2
  1d07 MOV  R6,A
  1d08 RET
```

So what I think it's doing is:

```
+-------------+----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
| Instruction |  Explanation   | A  | R2 | R5 | R6 | R7 |
+-------------+----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|             |                | 10 |  2 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
| XCH  A,R5   | Swap A with R5 |  5 |  2 | 10 |  6 |  7 |
| MOV  A,R7   | Copy R7 into A |  7 |  2 | 10 |  6 |  7 |
| XCH  A,R5   | Swap A with R5 | 10 |  2 |  7 |  6 |  7 |
| MOV  A,R5   | Copy R5 into A |  7 |  2 |  7 |  6 |  7 |
| MOV  R2,A   | Copy A into R2 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  6 |  7 |
| MOV  A,R6   | Copy R6 into A |  6 |  7 |  7 |  6 |  7 |
| MOV  R7,A   | Copy A into R7 |  6 |  7 |  7 |  6 |  6 |
| MOV  A,R2   | Copy R2 into A |  7 |  7 |  7 |  6 |  6 |
| MOV  R6,A   | Copy A into R6 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  6 |
| RET         | Return         |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  6 |
+-------------+----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

But that seems like it has a whole bunch of unnecessary steps. Wouldn't this be a lot more straightforward?

```
+-------------+----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
| Instruction |  Explanation   | A  | R2 | R5 | R6 | R7 |
+-------------+----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|             |                | 10 |  2 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
| XCH  A,R6   | Swap A with R6 |  6 |  2 |  5 | 10 |  7 |
| XCH  A,R7   | Swap A with R7 |  7 |  2 |  5 | 10 |  6 |
| MOV  R2,A   | Copy A into R2 |  7 |  7 |  5 | 10 |  6 |
| MOV  R5,A   | Copy A into R5 |  7 |  7 |  7 | 10 |  6 |
| MOV  R6,A   | Copy A into R6 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  6 |
| RET         | Return         |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  6 |
+-------------+----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

And this is me assuming you can't directly `MOV` or `XCH` between two `R#` registers. Being able to `MOV` wouldn't make a difference here I don't think, but if you can `XCH`, then you could shave off one more line like so:

```
+-------------+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
| Instruction |   Explanation   | A  | R2 | R5 | R6 | R7 |
+-------------+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
|             |                 | 10 |  2 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
| XCH  R6,R7  | Swap R6 with R7 | 10 |  2 |  5 |  7 |  6 |
| MOV  A,R6   | Copy R6 into A  |  7 |  2 |  5 |  7 |  6 |
| MOV  R2,A   | Copy A into R2  |  7 |  7 |  5 |  7 |  6 |
| MOV  R5,A   | Copy A into R5  |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  6 |
| RET         | Return          |  7 |  7 |  7 |  7 |  6 |
+-------------+-----------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

That being said, does anyone have any idea why it might have been implemented the way it was? I don't think it was to obfuscate the code—the chip I dumped it from ([P87C51RB2BA](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/8XC54_51FX_51RX.pdf)) has a "read-protect" bit that can be set when it's programmed, as well as the option to have it read out encrypted code. I figure if they had any reason to want to obfuscate the code, they would have set one of these, but (thankfully) it looks like they didn't, as I was able to dump the chip in cleartext just fine. (Unless my chip is merely "[functional by mistake](https://defectivebydesign.org/)".) And it would be weird to just obfuscate this one part anyway.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the function in question is called in quite a few places in the code; it's one of the most frequently-called functions I've seen in this firmware actually.

Here's some of the surrounding code, starting with another function that looks similarly convoluted (though it isn't called nearly as much, and I haven't analyzed it in detail)

```
                             **************************************************************
                             *                          FUNCTION                          *
                             **************************************************************
                             undefined FUN_CODE_1cd3()
             undefined         R7:1           
                             FUN_CODE_1cd3                                   XREF[9]:     FUN_CODE_0311:0462(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0311:04d8(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0311:0604(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0dd4:0dd6(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0f9b:0fa4(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0f9b:0fbd(c), 
                                                                                          ibus_2002_handler:1009(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1134:1136(c), 
                                                                                          ibus_3002_handler:116c(c)  
       CODE:1cd3 c8              XCH        A,R0
       CODE:1cd4 ef              MOV        A,R7
       CODE:1cd5 c8              XCH        A,R0
       CODE:1cd6 e6              MOV        A,@R0
       CODE:1cd7 fe              MOV        R6,A
       CODE:1cd8 08              INC        R0
       CODE:1cd9 e6              MOV        A,@R0
       CODE:1cda ff              MOV        R7,A
       CODE:1cdb 12 1c ff        LCALL      FUN_CODE_1cff                                    undefined FUN_CODE_1cff()
       CODE:1cde 22              RET
                             **************************************************************
                             *                          FUNCTION                          *
                             **************************************************************
                             undefined FUN_CODE_1cdf()
             undefined         R7:1           
                             FUN_CODE_1cdf                                   XREF[2]:     FUN_CODE_0cd4:0da7(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1569:158a(c)  
       CODE:1cdf 12 18 4d        LCALL      FUN_CODE_184d                                    undefined FUN_CODE_184d()
       CODE:1ce2 78 6c           MOV        R0,#0x6c
       CODE:1ce4 e6              MOV        A,@R0=>DAT_INTMEM_6c                             = ??
       CODE:1ce5 24 05           ADD        A,#0x5
       CODE:1ce7 f5 2f           MOV        DAT_INTMEM_2f,A                                  = ??
       CODE:1ce9 22              RET
                             **************************************************************
                             *                          FUNCTION                          *
                             **************************************************************
                             undefined FUN_CODE_1cea()
             undefined         R7:1           
                             FUN_CODE_1cea                                   XREF[1]:     FUN_CODE_165c:16b1(c)  
       CODE:1cea e5 1d           MOV        A,BANK3_R5                                       = ??
       CODE:1cec 60 06           JZ         LAB_CODE_1cf4
       CODE:1cee 12 1c 70        LCALL      FUN_CODE_1c70                                    undefined FUN_CODE_1c70()
       CODE:1cf1 12 1b d5        LCALL      FUN_CODE_1bd5                                    undefined FUN_CODE_1bd5()
                             LAB_CODE_1cf4                                   XREF[1]:     CODE:1cec(j)  
       CODE:1cf4 22              RET
                             **************************************************************
                             *                          FUNCTION                          *
                             **************************************************************
                             undefined FUN_CODE_1cf5()
             undefined         R7:1           
                             FUN_CODE_1cf5                                   XREF[3]:     FUN_CODE_0311:0520(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0311:0611(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1569:15b2(c)  
       CODE:1cf5 e5 2d           MOV        A,DAT_INTMEM_2d                                  = ??
       CODE:1cf7 04              INC        A
       CODE:1cf8 ff              MOV        R7,A
       CODE:1cf9 30 e7 02        JNB        ACC.7,LAB_CODE_1cfe                              = ??
       CODE:1cfc 7f 01           MOV        R7,#0x1
                             LAB_CODE_1cfe                                   XREF[1]:     CODE:1cf9(j)  
       CODE:1cfe 22              RET
                             **************************************************************
                             *                          FUNCTION                          *
                             **************************************************************
                             undefined FUN_CODE_1cff()
             undefined         R7:1           
                             FUN_CODE_1cff                                   XREF[23]:    FUN_CODE_0cd4:0cf2(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0cd4:0d17(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0cd4:0d23(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0cd4:0d2f(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0cd4:0d3b(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0cd4:0d61(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_0dd4:0e46(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1068:10d9(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1068:10f6(c), 
                                                                                          ibus_3004_handler:1190(c), 
                                                                                          ibus_3004_handler:11b5(c), 
                                                                                          ibus_3004_handler:11c1(c), 
                                                                                          ibus_3004_handler:11cd(c), 
                                                                                          ibus_3004_handler:11d9(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_184d:1861(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_184d:1886(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1988:1996(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1988:19b4(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1a5c:1a63(c), 
                                                                                          FUN_CODE_1a5c:1a76(c), [more]
       CODE:1cff cd              XCH        A,R5
       CODE:1d00 ef              MOV        A,R7
       CODE:1d01 cd              XCH        A,R5
       CODE:1d02 ed              MOV        A,R5
       CODE:1d03 fa              MOV        R2,A
       CODE:1d04 ee              MOV        A,R6
       CODE:1d05 ff              MOV        R7,A
       CODE:1d06 ea              MOV        A,R2
       CODE:1d07 fe              MOV        R6,A
       CODE:1d08 22              RET
                             LAB_CODE_1d09                                   XREF[1]:     CODE:1cc2(j)  
       CODE:1d09 7b 01           MOV        R3,#0x1
       CODE:1d0b 7a 00           MOV        R2,#0x0
       CODE:1d0d 02 1b 12        LJMP       LAB_CODE_1b12
                             DAT_CODE_1d10                                   XREF[1]:     start:152a(R)  
       CODE:1d10 01              undefined1 01h
                             DAT_CODE_1d11                                   XREF[1]:     start:1538(R)  
       CODE:1d11 1b              undefined1 1Bh
                             DAT_CODE_1d12                                   XREF[3]:     start:14ed(R), start:14ff(R), 
                                                                                          start:1547(R)  
       CODE:1d12 00              undefined1 00h
                             DAT_CODE_1d13                                   XREF[4]:     start:14f1(R), start:14ff(R), 
                                                                                          start:152a(R), start:154b(R)  
       CODE:1d13 01              undefined1 01h
                             DAT_CODE_1d14                                   XREF[3]:     start:14f1(R), start:152a(R), 
                                                                                          start:154f(R)  
       CODE:1d14 1f              undefined1 1Fh
                             DAT_CODE_1d15                                   XREF[2]:     start:152a(R), start:154f(R)  
       CODE:1d15 08              undefined1 08h
       CODE:1d16 00              ??         00h
```

**EDIT 2:** The device in question is a handheld programming device for Brinks alarm panels, the same one seen in [my video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ds8WccQH8_E).

Comment: Do you see this func actually called? Could it be that your tool disassembled a bunch of constants or smth? Does the FW look like it was written in C or in manual asm?

Comment: Also, any idea what this line means: "undefined R7:1 <RETURN>"? Can you include the bytes immed before and after this "func", preferrably with their hex values. The chunk does not look as meaningful code but you didn't give much context really.

Comment: True, it could well be data that was "disassembled".

Comment: Appears in deed as a non-code disassembly. The hex-bytes of the showed instructions makes no sense neither, e.g. representing a text.

Comment: @tum_: Sorry for the lack of context; I meant to say that yes, this function is called from very many places in the code. How would I tell if it was written in C or ASM?

Comment: @tum_: Here are the surrounding bytes: 70 12 1b d5 22 e5 2d 04 ff 30 e7 02 7f 01 22 **cd ef cd ed fa ee ff ea fe 22** 7b 01 7a 00 02 1b 12 01 1b 00 01 1f 08 00 80 c0 90 d0 7f 01 22 02 11 ee 00 00 00 00 00 00 (The bold part is the part I already showed above.) Also I meant to say, you can ignore that <RETURN> line; that's just the disassembler guessing at where it puts the return value.

Comment: It is better if you'd [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56085708/edit) your question to add any additional info. People don't like following all the comments.  My `preferably with their hex values` didn't mean hex values only, it's not much fun disassembling them manually. ;) `C or ASM` - if you do read disasm a lot you see patterns, compiler generates very different code from a human's one. But you probably don't do much reverse-engineering. I've never worked with 8051, so can't be of much help when it comes to specifics. If you see calls - you can see how regs are used on entry/exit.

Comment: @tum_: Oh right, I forgot. Thanks for reminding me; I'll do that. And I guess I took you too literally when you asked for the surrounding bytes; I have a habit of doing that, lol.

Comment: Ok. A lazy guess: the function swaps LSB & MSB of a 16bit variable passed via R6, R7 and it's compiler generated, hence the redundant code. The compiler is not optimising much (or optimisation was disabled), I've seen poor results on my z80 C compiler many years ago...

Comment: Actually, by "context" I also meant - what does the device do? This could also kind of help..

Comment: @tum_ I think you're right. The function at 1cd3 loads a 16 bit value and the bloated function at 1cff swaps the bytes. This byte-swapper function can be used at many places, so seeing a number of references is not surprising.

Comment: @tum_: I edited the question text to say what the device was. And I think you're right about the purpose being to swap bytes; that's what I was thinking as well, but I didn't know what the purpose of modifying the other registers was. The reason I think you're right is because this device is designed to communicate over a serial connection using little-endian, and the 8051 is big-endian. And I did see this function being called frequently after retrieving values that I know are sent over said connection, and I don't know of anything else it would need those values for. Why not post as answer?

Comment: Yes, I'll post an answer when I get to my PC. And yes, the thought of little-endian to network order conversion was the first thought that occurred to me once I've posted the "lazy guess".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through some guesswork (see comments) we came to the conclusion that

```
FUN_CODE_1cff
  1cff XCH  A,R5
  1d00 MOV  A,R7
  1d01 XCH  A,R5
  1d02 MOV  A,R5
  1d03 MOV  R2,A
  1d04 MOV  A,R6
  1d05 MOV  R7,A
  1d06 MOV  A,R2
  1d07 MOV  R6,A
  1d08 RET
```

is most probably a little-endian to big-endian conversion function generated by some non-optimising compiler. In C it would look something like:

```
uint16_t Convert16_BE2LE(uint16 var)
{
   uint16_t retVal;

   retVal = ((var & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((var & 0xFF00) >> 8);
   return retVal;
}
```

R5, R2 are used by the compiler as scratch registers.

As I mentioned in one of the comments, back in 2000-2005 I worked with ccz80 compiler by Wind River that produced similar results in terms of optimisation. It would pretty much just translate a particular C construct into a fixed sequence of opcodes. As a result, the code was correct but looked terribly suboptimal for someone who was used to manual assembly programming. On the other hand, though, this allowed the compiler to be cheap, tiny (~150-200K) and very fast.

Comment: re: your last paragraph: [Why do C to Z80 compilers produce poor code?](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6095).  Partly because C is a poor fit for Z80, but also that back in the day when compilers had to be self-hosting *on* Z80 machines there wasn't room (or development time) for an optimizer anywhere near as good as modern gcc.  (Or even gcc from ~2000).  Some of the details in that Retrocomputing question and the answers are more interesting than that simple summary, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm, I haven't come across that thread and this is a bit surprising as I do monitor the `z80` tag (which is not very active these days). Ah, I can see now that this is not SO but a different resource altogether. Thanks for this I will give it a read. This chip from the 70s remains my "first love" and it paid my bills for ~7-8 years, half of which was in XXI century. I believe, they are still around in some low-end systems but not in my domain (POS terminals/pinpads).

Comment: retrocomputing.SE is still a stackexchange site, not "totally separate".  A bit surprising that there weren't better cross compilers targeting Z80 for embedded applications in 2000 or so, because many of the missed optimizations like this one are pretty localized.  I think ARM (or PIC, 8051, and AVR in the lower end) has mostly taken over that nice these days, but yeah I've heard of embedded 8086 and Z80.  I haven't done embedded development myself, though.